# Google sheets max cells limits and mitigations

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, bigdata, analytics, counting

I'd read online that Google sheets has a max cell limit of 5 million cells. A sheet that I'm currently working on has well and above passed that limit (including blank cells).

1. What is the new limit?
2. Also I'd manually checked how many cells I was using. Is there any
   function or script that I can use to keep a check?
3. The sheet I'm working on is going to only get bigger and it's already lagging heavily. I'd love some suggestions on which platform I could move to next to handle such big data. There are so many options, it's mindboggling. I use Google sheets mainly for it's ease in collaboration, presentability and ease of use. Any other tool with these traits but with an ability to handle bigger data?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using Google Sheets.

Comment: I would also vote to close this question as "needs focus" because you have 3 questions in one post.   Each post should focus on just one problem.

Comment: I would also vote to close this question as off-topic because both questions 2 and 3 ask for recommendations of 3rd-party scripts and services.

Comment: Excuse my incomprehension here, which would be the right forum for me to pose Q2 and 3? Actually meant Q2 as a coding question asking for a google script or function to automate the count of used cells. Thank you for your clarification. cheers.

Comment: There is not always a Stack Exchange site for every question.

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. in the early years, it was 5 million cells. last year this was upgraded to 10 million cells

   you can follow updates at: **https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/search/label/Google%20Sheets**
2. try:

   [image]
3. take a look on [Google DataStudio](https://datastudio.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to check the cell limit was to try and add a huge amount of lines at the end of the document, which gave me this error message:

[image: Error]

This reads: "**An error has occurred: This action would increase the number of cells in the worksheet above the limit of 10000000 cells**".

However, when I used one more digit, I got a different message:

[image: row error]

That one reads: "**Oops, enter a number between 1 and 5000000**", suggesting the maximum number of *rows* you can have is 5 million, while the max of *cells* can be up to 10 million. I'm  not sure about the columns, but I'd say it is the as the row's limit.