# How to speed up writing onto google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write an add on for google spread sheet that takes a csv and write onto a new sheet. The problem is that the csv can potentially be very large, reaching up to around a million rows. I managed to fix the cell limit problem by deleting unnecessary columns, but my script keeps timing out even at 500,000 rows. So I was wondering if there is a way to increase the write speed?

Here is my code where I create a new sheet and populate it with the csv data:

```
function writeDataToSheet(data,sheetName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  const neededColumns = data[0].length;
  const totalColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  const columnsToDelete = totalColumns - neededColumns;
  if(columnsToDelete > 0) sheet.deleteColumns(totalColumns , columnsToDelete);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}
```

To be clear, data is supposed to be a 2 dimensional array, converted from csv data using `Utilities.parseCsv()`.

Comment: You should keep in mind that a single Spreadsheet file has an approximate limit of 5 million cells. So if your file has more than 5 columns, at 1 million rows, then it will probably fail.

Comment: It looks like your are writing about as fast as it can be done.  But I would recommend that you reconsider putting your data into a database.

Comment: @Mr Shane, Hey thanks for the heads up, but I read on a different stack over flow post that the 5 million cell limit has increased to 10 million now. However, you can only have 5 million rows.

Edit: here is the post that I am basing this off of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70125623/google-sheets-max-cells-limits-and-mitigations

Comment: Hey @Cooper, thanks for the recommendation. I may be wrong since I am still lacking experience and knowldege, but I think the csv data is already in a database since it's stored inside aws s3. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: I'm just thinking thinking that you have so much data that a spreadsheet is not the best container for it.

Comment: Try to time everyline using `console.time`. You can use advanced Google services/sheets api if setValues/delete columns is slow.

Comment: officially it is still 5 million: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603, however Google may be rolling out new higher limits, which will be good to see. thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my measured benchmark, when the data is large, when Sheets API is used instead of the Spreadsheet service (`SpreadsheetApp`), the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) This situation is almost the same with and without V8 runtime. This has already been mentioned in [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536828/how-to-speed-up-writing-onto-google-spreadsheet#comment124689969_70536828). In your script, when Sheets API is used, it becomes as follows.

**Before you use this modified script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).**

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your `data` is used. Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

##### To:

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: data}, ss.getId(), sheet.getSheetName(), {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, from `To be clear, data is supposed to be a 2 dimensional array, converted from csv data using Utilities.parseCsv().`, the CSV data before `data` is directly used. Please modify your script as follows. So, please directly put `csvData` to the following request.

##### From:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

##### To:

```
function writeDataToSheet(csvData, sheetName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  const requests = { requests: [{ pasteData: { data: csvData, coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }] };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(requests, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Benchmark: Importing CSV Data to Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was away for new years. Thanks for the answer, It looks promising. I will try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: @Josee Thank you for replying. It's no problem. When my answer was useful, I'm glad.