# How to parse large .CSV files(~15MB) in Google Sheets using custom appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a custom app script to import the .csv files into Google Sheets. However, for large CSV files,  the script takes longer to parse. Any ideas on how to optimize this?
Here is the code that I have

```js
function importCSVData(csvData) {
  // Parse the CSV data into an array to check if it's empty
  var csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvData);

  // Check if the CSV file is empty or has 0 columns
  if (csvArray.length === 0 || csvArray[0].length === 0) {
    // Return a message to indicate that the file is empty
    return 'The CSV file is empty or has 0 columns.';
  }

  // Create an array of column names with serial numbers
  var columnNames = csvArray[0].map(function(columnName, index) {
    return (index + 1) + '. ' + columnName;
  });

  // Prompt the user to select columns
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Select Columns to Import',
    'Enter the column numbers separated by spaces that you want to import:\n' + columnNames.join('\n'),
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );

  if (result.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var selectedColumns = result.getResponseText().split(' ');

    // Convert the user input to column indices (subtract 1 to match JavaScript array indexing)
    var columnIndicesToImport = selectedColumns.map(function(selectedColumn) {
      return parseInt(selectedColumn) - 1;
    });

    // Filter and create a subset array based on selected column indices
    var subsetArray = csvArray.map(function(row) {
      return columnIndicesToImport.map(function(columnIndex) {
        return row[columnIndex];
      });
    });

    // Append the subset of CSV data to the target sheet
    var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet-id');
    var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, subsetArray.length, subsetArray[0].length).setValues(subsetArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70536828

Comment: how many rows is it?

Comment: @MattKing around 500k.

Comment: A Google Sheet with that many rows won't be very useful because of how slow it'll be.  I'd recommend using excel tbh

Comment: @MattKing This is actually a part of my assignment to create a script for importing CVS files to google sheets. After a bit of research, I found out that there is something called Google Sheets API which is optimal for large CSV files

Comment: check out BigQuery too